# need tips on how to reduce capital gains of primary residence sold for $2.2M this month in California

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, capital-gains-tax, california

What all can we do to reduce the long term Fed & Calif
cap gains tax on our primary residence for 21 years?

All we can think of is:
depreciation and expense of original landscaping.

DETAILS...
House originally purchased in 1998 for $867k.
$50k original landscape in 1998-1999.
Married couple filing joint.
We now live in a 2nd home, in Calif, but were in residence of sold home for 3 yrs of past 5 yrs.
(sold home has been rented out since May 2019)

TURBO TAX FORECAST $240K IN TAX ...
Used TT and temporarily, just to see diff, added sale of $2.2M house to our 2019 tax return and TT increased Fed + Calif. by $240k ie. the Ftax on sale of primary residence.

TAX CPU DAUGHTER WHO FORECASTS COULD BE $375K...
CPU Daughter used same data and predicts Fed+Calif tax could be $375k.

Comment: How much did you pay for the house? Was it used for business or just as a primary residence?

Comment: The long-term capital-gain rate is actually advantageous compared to past history. But capital-gains can be delayed or reduced by investing in Opportunity Zone funds.

Comment: Depreciation will reduce your tax as you are renting, but actually increase it when you sell because it's recaptured then.

Comment: Are you excluding $500k of the gain with the [Section 121 exclusion](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc701)? That should help a lot.

Comment: Like I said, paid $867k for house. Residence from 1998 thru April 2019 then rental from May 2019 until sold on Aug 2020.  Excluding $500k of course.  S Spring, thanks for OZ tip.